# vertical gap between 2 image in outlook 2013 when HTML as a text

Tags: html, css, outlook

i created mailing but there is a vertical gap between 2 images and i read all solutions about this problem and not solved.
last chance is typing this portal and ask you guys :(

first i open below code on notepad++ and change it then outlook 13 attach file => as a text => then boom vertical gap showing up.

here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>mailing</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<table id="Table_01" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1">
            <a href="mailto:info@ygtur.com">
                <img src="http://yucel.ygtur.com/mailing/erkenrez/images/mailing_12.jpg" style="display: block;"></a></td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
            <a href="http://www.ygtur.com/">
                <img src="http://yucel.ygtur.com/mailing/erkenrez/images/mailing_13.jpg" style="display: block;"></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

[here is the picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfph7.png)

Comment: you dont have any widths for your `table` or `td`. So the `td` could be just guessing how wide it needs to be. I placed it into a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ty6aw4j5/

Answer (score 0):

You could try using css to style the table instead of using `border= cellpadding=` etc. In fact you already tagged the question as `css`, so I guess you saw it coming :-)

Perhaps Outlook adds its own css if it does not find any, or the view engine that it uses may apply defaults that you are not expecting.

*EDIT:*
You have whitespace between the `<a href>` and `<img>` tags. You should remove that, it may be the cause of your problem. It wouldn't be a problem if the link had just text, but now it has text(whitespace) + an image, and both will show.

Comment: not about outlook issue i think. the gap showed up on gmail too.

Comment: i removed <a href> tags for example. But

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title>mailing</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<table id="Table_01" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
  <td colspan="1">
    <img src="http://yucel.ygtur.com/mailing/erkenrez/images/mailing_12.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>
  <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
    <img src="http://yucel.ygtur.com/mailing/erkenrez/images/mailing_13.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>